# How do I make images show up in UWP version of my Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have a simple Xaml like this:

```
...
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid Padding="0,40,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image  Grid.Row ="0" Source="iMobile"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        WidthRequest="260" HeightRequest="129"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

The image `iMobile` shows up on `Android` and `ios`. For `Android` I have the different sizes for the image in the separate drawable folders. For `ios`, I have the different sizes of the image in the Assets catalog.

I have tried to do same for UWP but nothing seems to work. Here are some of the things I have tried doing:

- I have added the image to the root directory for the UWP project but that doesn't work.
- I added the image to the Assets directory but that did not work.
- I tried adding `.scale-100`, `.scale-200` and `.scale-400` to the name of the image file (tried them all separately) but that did not work.
- I also tried putting the image in a directory named **scale-100** but that did not work either.

Any ideas what might be causing my issue and how I can fix this? It is super frustrating that something this trivial is taking so much of my time.

**Update:**
I tried using a URL as the source instead of iMobile and this does not work for UWP either but it does work for Android, and idea why this might be?

Comment: did you set the build action to "Content"?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images

Comment: Yes build action is set to content

Comment: @Jason it seems to be that the Image is not working at all, I tried using a URL as the Source instead of iMobile and this does not show up for UWP but it does work or Android, any idea why this might be?

Comment: I know very little about UWP.  I'd suggest you download one of the samples from Xamarin and examine how their images work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make images show up in UWP version of my Xamarin.Forms application

Please refer [Images in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows) official document. Xamarin form support [Native resolutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#native-resolutions-retina-and-high-dpi).

> UWP image file names can be suffixed with .scale-xxx before the file extension, where xxx is the percentage of scaling applied to the asset, e.g. myimage.scale-200.png. Images can then be referred to in code or XAML without the scale modifier, e.g. just myimage.png. The platform will select the nearest appropriate asset scale based on the display's current DPI.

If you placed image file in the UWP Assets folder, you could use the following xaml, And please note the default blank xamarin app iamge file' color is white, we need set black background to highlight them.

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
    <Image>
        <Image.Source>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/LargeTile.png" />
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="LargeTile.png" />
                <On Platform="Android" Value="LargeTile.png" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have read through the documentation in the link you provided, and I have done the steps stated there, I put the image in the root directory of my UWP project and used iMobile.png but it still doesn't work. What is even more confusing is that I tried using a google image URL for the Image source instead and it still doesn't work. However when I tried using this link for the image source (in place of check.png) in the sample project at https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Todo it works fine, any ideas as to why it may not work for me?

Comment: Could you share your imobile png file  for testing?

Comment: So I figured it out, it turns out all i had to do was add **.png** to iMobile to get it to work for UWP, however using a URL for image source still did not work, I don't know why that is but since this works, it's less of an issue for me.

Comment: Could you share your image uri for testing?

Comment: https://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/google/66903-google-pay-gboard-platform-logo-cloud.png

Comment: I used your image uri and set it to source directly, it could work well, I could not reproduce your problem.

Comment: I made a small project and used it in there as well and it worked fine. This is a mystery to me too but I have found a work around for it and your answer helped so thank you